# Azure mobile service for Android using Azure database

Tags: android, wcf, mobile, azure

I have built a database using Windows Azure, and current goal is to use a mobile service to query that database in an Android app.

I built a WCF service that gives me my desired results, then realized you can create a mobile service directly on the Azure site. After creating the mobile service on Azure and telling it to use my Azure db, I don't see anywhere to write a query that the service will use to return data. Do I still need my WCF service? Do I upload it into the Azure mobile service somehow? I'm probably missing something simple here.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-android/) out. See the "Update the app to use the mobile service for data access" section.

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private private MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable;

mClient = new MobileServiceClient("MobileServiceUrl", "AppKey", this)
                                      .withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);

mToDoTable.where().field("complete").eq(false)
.execute(new TableQueryCallback<ToDoItem>() {
     public void onCompleted(List<ToDoItem> result, 
             int count, Exception exception, 
             ServiceFilterResponse response) {

            if(exception == null){
                mAdapter.clear();

                for (ToDoItem item : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(item);
                }
            } else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
    }
});
```

Also, see this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/21/playing-with-the-query-object-in-read-operations-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may find this blog post useful: [How to use Windows Azure Table Storage in Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Use-Table-Storage-in-0b6bcbc7).

This shows how you can use Windows Azure Mobile Services to build a service on top of Windows Azure table storage that can be accessed from a mobile client app (Windows Phone, Android, Windows Store, iOS, or HTML 5. You don't need your WCF service, you can include the query in the **Read** script in your Mobile Service.

There is another example here that shows how to create Mobile Services scripts to access a MongoDB database instead of SQL Azure or Windows Azure Table storage: http://www.contentmaster.com/azure/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-with-a-mongodb-database/